# how does spring manage to populate objects from view to controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

could someone explain to me how does spring manage to populate objects from a form in the view?

take a look at my example

Person class:

```
public class Person {

    private String name;
    private String password;

    /*
    constructors, getters and setters
    */
}
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HomeController {

    @GetMapping
    public String showForm() {
        return "form";
    }

    @PostMapping
    public String processForm(@ModelAttribute("person") Person person) {
        return "displayForm";
    }
}
```

form.html :

```
<body>
    <form method="post">
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name">
        <label for="password">password:</label>
        <input type="text" name="password">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
```

displayform.html :

```
<body>
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <span th:text="${person.name}"></span>
    <br>
    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <span th:text="${person.password}"></span>
</body>
```

i was thinking this example will return a null object but it worked.

the question is how does spring populate the person without defining a `th:object=${person}` form attribute for the form?

Comment: Form values are bound to fields of `Person` thank to `name` attributes in your `<input>` elements. If names didn't didn't match `Person` fields then the `Person` object would contain nulls. `th:` works just one way to display data so it's not helpful at all on form submission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Spring Web MVC, `DispatcherServlet` class works as the front controller. It is responsible to manage the flow of the spring mvc application.

The whole flow works as below -

1. First request will be received by `DispatcherServlet`.
2. `DispatcherServlet` will take the help of `HandlerMapping` and get to know the Controller class name associated with the given request.
3. Now the request transfer to the Controller, and then controller will process the request by executing appropriate methods and returns `ModelAndView` object (contains Model data and View name) back to the `DispatcherServlet`.
4. `DispatcherServlet` send the model object to the `ViewResolver` to get the actual view page.
5. In final step  `DispatcherServlet` will pass the `Model object` to the View page to display the result.

Comment: appreciate the big picture thing here but what i asked was about the details.